# Use parameters of latexcommand in two .tex files

Tags: parameters

Im quite new to Latex and haven't found anything yet to help me with my problem. My problem is that i want to write the output of a command to another .tex file.

I want to use the custom command `\errordescripton{x}{y}{z}` in descrition.tex. The parameters x,y,z should be used within the errordescripton command but also a summary of each error in a summary.tex. Like the name suggests i then want to create a table within the summary.tex which lists only the content of the parameters x,y,z

In description.tex i write:
`\errordescripton{x}{y}{z}`

Which triggeres this:
`\newcommand{\errordescripton}[3]{ #1 #2 #3 }`

In summary.tex after the output the table should be look like this:

| Asset | shortdesc | longdesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | #2 | #3 |

Comment: this is basically how glossaries or tables of contents work. You could perhaps use the glossaries package (especially if you want to sort your summary into alphabetic order rather than the order in the first file) or at a lower level you can use `\write` to write out each entry to an auxiliary file.